# Java Closing an IOStream in finally giving error: Unhandled Exception: java.io.IOException

Tags: java, exception

Coming from C#, I would typically use this pattern when interacting with streams (note that I'm using Java classes here, but I'm referring to a pattern in C#):

```
HttpURLConnection ServiceConnection;
DataOutputStream ConnectionStream;

try {
    ServiceConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ServiceUrl.openConnection();
    ConnectionStream = new DataOutputStream(ServiceConnection.getOutputStream());

    //...
}
finally {
    ConnectionStream.close();
    ServiceConnection.Disconnect();
}
```

From my understanding, for checked Exceptions like IOException, I need to include a catch block. Fair enough. So I changed my code as follows:

```
HttpURLConnection ServiceConnection;
DataOutputStream ConnectionStream;

try {
    ServiceConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ServiceUrl.openConnection();
    ConnectionStream = new DataOutputStream(ServiceConnection.getOutputStream());

    //...
}
catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
    //...
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //...
}
finally {
    ConnectionStream.close();
    ServiceConnection.Disconnect();
}
```

However, this code gives me the following error: Unhandled Exception: java.io.IOException on the line that I attempt to close the stream in the finally block.

What am I not understanding here? I thought that finally blocks were where you are supposed to put cleanup code and I thought that closing a stream here is the perfect candidate for that?

Comment: A block of code in `finally` is a block of code like any other; also, if you use Java 7+, consider using a try-with-resources statement

Comment: `DataOutputStream.close` can throw `IOexception` so you have to surround it with a `try catch` block. Also, you are not checking wether or not `ConnectionStream` is null. You might end up with a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use apache's [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) library. It has a method called close quietly.

```
finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(connectionStream);
    }
```

Otherwise you would have to surround the close method with try/catch

```
finally {
        if (connectionStream != null) {
            try {
                connectionStream.close();
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
                // Nothing to do
            }
        }
    }
```